# How do I continue a for loop without going to the next index? - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, keyword

is there any way to continue a for loop without going to the next index?

Example:

```
for player in range(players):
    name = input("what is your name? ").lower()
    if name == "john cena":
        print("Hey! That's not your real name!")
        [some keyword or function that allows the magic to happen]
    elif name == "donald trump":
        print("Hi Mr. President!")
        [the same keyword or function that allows the magic to happen]

    player_names.append(name)
```

Shell:

```
============ RESTART =========

what is your name? luke
what is your name? john cena
Hey! That's not your real name!
what is your name? donald trump
Hi Mr. President!
what is your name? mickey mouse
what is your name? nobody
>>> player_names
["luke", "mickey mouse", "nobody"]
```

Comment: Nope! You can put a `while` loop in there, though.

Comment: Aww... that's disappointing... thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is intended to allow you to iterate over each element once, without having to worry about how to actually move to the next index.

```
for each player:
   # do something
```

If you require more control over when, or if, you would like to move to the next index, you can use a `while` loop.

```
while (some_condition_is_true):
   # do something
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on this REALLY hard game that has lots of confusing code. Gotta find out a way to replace the for loop with a while loop.